# Does your Xcode's snapshot feature well work?

Tags: xcode

My Xcode's snapshot feature isn't working well. (version 4.2.1)

I have used the snapshot feature as this sequence.

1. Write a code. (example code)

   @autoreleasepool {

   ```
   [self CreateStatus];
   [self TurnOnStatus];
   [self schedule:@selector(Processing)];
   ```

   }
2. Execute the create snapshot feature of xcode.
3. And then adding a code.

   @autoreleasepool {

   ```
   [self CreateStatus];
   [self TurnOnStatus];
   [self schedule:@selector(Processing)];
   NSLog(@"snap shot feature test"); <== Adding this line.
   ```

   }
4. And then execute the restore snapshot feature. (restore to now making.)

When do this,

Xcode have to delete the "nslog" line, but the line isn't deleted.

or restore to snapshot that created at far past.

Have you ever had this experience?

or there is there someone that knows the reason?

or I use this feature the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use the restore feature, Xcode creates an entirely new copy of the application, leaving the source files unmodified where I was working. It was easy to be confused at first, since the code was all the same, but then I realized that now I had 2 copies, one was from the snapshot, and one was with the modifications. I had to explicitly find and open the restored version.

Hopefully this is what's happening for you :-) Pay close attention as you do the restore, it may ask you for a location on your drive to restore to. Afterwards, you have to manually go and open that new copy of your project.